# WinDbg do not release symbol files after unloading modules

Tags: windbg

From ages I was using windbg command:

```
!realod -u
```

to unload all symbols and release symbol files (.pdb) so I can freely rebuild projects. However recently (I mean at least few months ago) it stopped to work this way. Like usual windbg react to command:

```
kd> !reload -u
Unloaded all modules
```

but files are still locked by windbg executable. I can of course do usual trick with file rename so I can run rebuild, but it is getting really annoying (and time wasting). Did someone maybe managed to get around of this bug nicely and want to share?

Comment: if you close windbg does it release the dlls?

Comment: which windbg version do you use?

Comment: It is Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.413)

Comment: Yes closing windbg release this pdb files.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it using Process Explorer by SysInternals
can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Open it with administrative rights, and show the lower pane (Ctrl + L)
you'll see any open handle by the selected process. Select your windbg.exe and then - close the relevant file handle.